# comma-comma-at in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am confused about how comma-comma-at does what it does.

An example of use of comma-comma-at is in [Is there a use for double unquote (double comma) when defining a Lisp macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17938242/is-there-a-use-for-double-unquote-double-comma-when-defining-a-lisp-macro)

It seems to me that

```
(let ((parms '(x y)))
  ``(beg ,,@parms end))
```

expands to or something equivalent to

```
`(beg ,x ,y end)
```

How does it expands to that?

I was thinking, if I evaluate the double backquote form, it causes the second comma to do its work, and the result is:

```
`(beg ,<splice stuff here> end)
```

and it looks like Lisp interpreter should complain and say "I don't know what it means to splice stuff before a comma" in the sense that when Lisp encounters

```
`,@abc
```

it would be likely to say "I don't know what it means to splice stuff before a backquote. Don't ever do that again."

But somehow, the interpreter does not complain and simply choose to do

```
`(beg <splice stuff here and write comma in front of each of them> end)
```

Is that compatible with rules in [CLHS backquote](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm)?

---

For readers information, comments following the answer refer to an old version of the answer, and lead to update of the answer. New readers don't need to read the comments.

---

Also see [CHLS "innermost backquoted form should be expanded first" meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008099/chls-innermost-backquoted-form-should-be-expanded-first-meaning)

Comment: +1 for asking a LISP question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_df.htm) states: "If the backquote syntax is nested, the *innermost* backquoted form should be expanded first. This means that if several commas occur in a row, the leftmost one belongs to the innermost backquote."

So, the first comma unquotes the second backquote; the `,@` then splices in the contents of `parms`, as all quotes have been undone. Unquoting does not "replace" forms in steps as you describe - the commas just back up in the structure of backquoted forms when deciding how to evaluate the contained forms.

```
(let ((parms '(x y)))
  `(list 'beg ,@parms 'end))
```

obviously evaluates to `(list 'beg x y 'end)`, which is what you are after here; producing a form that creates the desired structure as its output. The additional outer backquote is simply a shorthand for this syntax, in the same manner as `'(foo bar)` is (equality issues aside) a shorthand for `(list 'foo 'bar)`.

Comment: In CLISP, `(let ((parms '(x y))) ``(beg ,,parms end))` (=A) evaluates to `(CONS 'BEG (CONS (X Y) '(END)))` (=B1) which is different from `'(beg (x y) end)` (=B2). B1 and B2 are different in that evaluation of B1 results in error, while evaluation of B2 result in `(BEG (X Y) END)` without error. And `(let ((parms '(x y))) ``(beg ,,@parms end))` (=P) and `(let ((parms '(x y))) \`'(beg ,@parms end))` (=Q) seem different in that double evaluation of P results in error while double evaluation of Q does not.

Comment: @JisangYoo: No, `(cons 'beg (cons (x y) '(end)))` is the same as `'(beg (x y) end)`, in the sense that it evaluates to the same form `(beg (x y) end)`. This was the sense I meant when I said "to something along the lines of" and not simply "to".

Comment: But `(cons 'beg (cons (x y) '(end)))` does not evaluate to `(beg (x y) end)` because `(x y)` is not quoted.

Comment: SBCL seems to give results easier to reason. In SBCL, A evaluates to `\`(BEG ,(X Y) END)`  (=B0). B0 is equivalent to B1, the CLISP result, but neither B0 nor B1 is equivalent to B2.

Comment: Sorry, this is true. My last edit was a step in the wrong direction. I'm primarily using ccl, and it evaluates A into `(LIST* 'BEG (LIST* (X Y) '(END)))` - I didn't realize there was no quote for `(X Y)`. However, the pre-edit version, with which I replaced the answer now, should be correct.

Comment: Also figured out a rationale from a bit different perspective, which now makes sense at least to me :)